# Confused with PHP While Loop

Tags: php

I have the following output:

```
12345: 1
1234: 7
1234: 7
1234: 6
1234: 4
```

It is produced from a URL which ends in "?id=12345". What's supposed to happen is that the id is incremented by 1 when the id exists in the database or it is added when it doesn't. The last result produced by 1234 is right, but how do I stop the previous results of 1234 from being produced?

```
while ($row = $database->row()->fetch()) {
    $id    = $row["id"];
    $count = $row["count"];

    if ($id != $_GET["id"]) {
        $insert = new MySQLConnect();
        $insert->query("INSERT INTO links VALUES (:id, 1);");
        $insert->run(array("id" => $_GET["id"]);
    } elseif ($id == $_GET["id"]) {
        $update = new MySQLConnect();
        $update->query("UPDATE links SET count=count + 1 WHERE id=:id;");
        $update->run(array("id" => $_GET["id"]);
    }

}
```

EDIT:

```
function display_data()
{
    $display = new MySQLConnect();
    $display->query("SELECT * FROM links;");
    $display->run();

    while ($row = $display->row()->fetch()) {
        $id    = $row["id"];
        $count = $row["count"];

        $GLOBALS["output"] .= $id . ": " . $count . "<br/>";
    }

}
```

Comment: Just a side note: What would happen if I went to `?id='',''); DROP TABLE links; --`?

Comment: do you know what while loop does? difference foreach and while?

Comment: [Beware of Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Escape your varibales in queries.

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat It drops the table links

Comment: `elseif ($id == $_GET["id"])` Thank you Captain Obvious!

Comment: @user1408643 Rocket was trying to demonstrate to you how easy it would be to destroy your database because you are implanting a variables value directly into the SQL query without preparing. That is called SQL Injection. If that was a form field, like Name, and you put it in the database like that, I could make my name DROP TABLE links and it would empty your table. Google SQL Injection and then learn Mysqli-PDO Prepared Statements

Comment: Guys, the site is probably in the dev stages. It's not like he is going to upload it like this.

Comment: @EisaAdil That's a fantastic reason to build something crappy. You don't think learning it right BEFORE something bad happens is a good idea?

Comment: OK Guys let's please get back on topic. The site is currently in development and I'm just playing around with the logic as in it's just a sketch in PHP. Please don't waste your own time and the reader's as they will have to read through it just to get the answer.

Comment: If you only want to increment/create new record, why do you have "while ($row = $database->row()->fetch())"? What are you trying to do with that part? Shouldn't you just create/increment the ID you are getting from $_GET ?  Also, you are giving the output, but you don't have any "echo" statements listed. Can you paste that part too?

Comment: @Rottingham He is just playing around with code write now, and wants us to help him with logic, not advice him on things he definitely knows about.

Comment: What the hell has happened to my spellings? * right

Comment: I've updated the code to show parameterized queries being used with my PDO MySQL wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the "while" if you just want to create/update the ID sent as parameter

```
$useId = (int)$_GET["id"];
$insert = new MySQLConnect();
$insert->query("INSERT INTO `links` (`id`, `count`) VALUES ('$useId', 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `count` = `count` + 1");
$insert->run();
```

Comment: I tried your solution but I keep getting a new entry into the database and nothing is being incremented. The output I get is:12345: 250
12345: 144
12345: 1

Comment: You  should make a primary key on the id field